# Codahale Metrics Anomaly

Tags: graph, metrics, rate, codahale-metrics

I am using codahale metrics to measure the performance (latency,throughout) of my system. I see some anomaly in the fact that the one minute rate (even 5 minute and 15 minute) latency metrics are very high (10x times)  as compared to the mean latency metrics. 
Could there be a logical explanation to this?
Thanks

Comment: I have similar problem, it's 100 times less than should be :) looks like problem is reporting...

Answer (score 0):

This can be due to the difference in reporting interval of the metric library and minimum retention interval of carbon cache defined in storage-schemas.conf (in case you use one). They should match afaik.